# Find and remove partial link from existing href

Tags: jquery, html

I have been finding examples on this but till now I am still so confuse about getting to work for this.

I have an existing `<a href="http://www.sitename.com/dir1/dir2">` and I need to insert into this link with "upload" dir.

So the end result will be `<a href="upload/dir2">`

How do I remove `http://www.sitename.com/dir1` and insert the "upload" into the link?

Hope you guys understand what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: look at [string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

Comment: Wow. I usually will do some research before posting anything in here due to the fact that stackoverflow actually discourage repeated questions. I have already stated that I am confused with all the examples that I have seen. Plus the link you put doesn't even show that it is relevant to my tagged question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it,

```
var link=$('a.your_link').attr('href');
var new_link=link.replace("http://www.sitename.com/dir1","upload");
$("a.your_link").attr("href",new_link)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a").attr("href","upload/dir2")
```

Since you're using JQuery, just try the above

Comment: Yes, it's just for illustrative purposes. It would be good to incorporate an id or class to target the link more uniquely. The key point was the attr()

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

```
    var $that = $('a');
    var oriHref = $that.attr('href');
    var newHref = oriHref.replace('http://www.sitename.com/dir1', 'upload');
    $that.attr('href',newHref);
```